# Please, how can I get the following drawing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, graphs, technical-drawing

I was wondering what would be better ways to get the following diagram with tikz?

Thanks

[image: Ladder Logic Diagram]

The code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[line width=1mm] (0,0) -- (0,10) node (Line1) [above] {$L_1$};
%---
\draw (0,9) -- (1,9) node (rung00) [left] {$0000$};
%---
\draw (1,8.5) -- (1,9.5) node (n1) [] {};
\draw (1.5,8.5) -- (1.5,9.5) node (n2) [] {};
%---
\draw (1.5,9) -- (4.5,9) node (n3) [] {};
%---
\draw (4.5,8.5) -- (4.5,9.5) node (n4) [] {};
\draw (5,8.5) -- (5,9.5) node (n5) [] {};
\draw (4.5,8.5) -- (5,9.5) node (n5) [] {};
\draw (5,9) -- (7,9) node (n6) [] {};
%---
\draw (7.2,8.5) arc (-150:-210:1cm);
\draw (7.8,9.5) arc (30:-30:1cm);
%---
\draw (8,9) -- (10,9);  
\draw (0,7) -- (1,7) node (n8) [] {};
%---
\draw (1,6.5) -- (1,7.5) node (n9) [] {};
\draw (1.5,6.5) -- (1.5,7.5) node (n10) [] {};
%---
\draw (1.5,7) -- (4,7) node (n11) [] {};
%---
\draw (4,7) -- (4,9) node (n12) [] {};
%---
%\draw[red] (0,0) -- ([xshift=3pt] 1,1);

\draw[line width=1mm] (10,0) -- (10,10) node (Line1) [above] {$L_2$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: The commands you are using require the `pst-circ` package to be loaded. (Also you have a typo in your title: `\LaTeX` not `\Latex`.)  If I fix that,  remove the `pst-pdf` package, and then compile using latex+dvips or xelatex the document works. There is also the `circuitikz` package, which uses TikZ instead of `pstricks`. TikZ is (IMO) better documented, and there are far more users of it here than of `pstricks`.

Comment: Nice, Alan! Thanks                                                                                                So I needed to replace these two lines:                                                        % \usepackage{pstricks}
% \usepackage{pst-pdf}                                                                                    by the one given by Alan to get it work:                                                      \usepackage{pst-circ}

Comment: There's no harm to leave in the `pstricks` package (although it's loaded by `pst-circ`).  But you should be compiling with `latex+dvips` not `pdflatex`.

Comment: Is it possible to get the 2 first rung-lines of the graph, because I don't know how to join 2 objects or items with a horizontal line nor how to put the vertical lines?

Comment: Yes, I compiled with xelatex.

Comment: Yes Alan, I checked out the Tikz-Pgf manual but didn't see an example or elements of this drawing and found pstricks for the first time. I prefer Tikz though but don't know how to get this drawing with it :-(

Comment: Here is my progress: after paying close attention to the first block of the initial posted code, I learn 2 things. The first thing is that the (7,7) right after the begin{pstricks} is the sum of the 2 defined nodes in the function. The second is, I can join 2 object by using "multidipole and put the object in curly bracket." This works with resistors and capacitors but for the elements I want/need to use, it is working. The code follows

Answer (score 5):

Use always `xelatex` and do not load package `inputenc` it is not needed for `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-circ}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(7,7)
    \pnodes(0,0){A}(7,7){B}
    \multidipole(A)(B)\resistor{$R$}%
    \capacitor[linecolor=red]{$C$}%
    \diode{$D$}{}
\end{pspicture}

\begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \xio[plcaddress=I:1/0,
    plcsymbol=Symbol](0,0)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is my progress: after paying close attention to the first block of the initial posted code, I learn 2 things. The first thing is that the (7,7) right after the begin{pstricks} is the sum of the 2 defined nodes in the function. The second is, I can join 2 object by using "multidipole and put the object in curly bracket." This works with resistors and capacitors but for the elements I want/need to use, it is working. The code follows

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{}

    \usepackage{pst-circ} 

    %opening
    \title{My First Ladder Logic with \LaTex}
    \author{Guy}

    \begin{document}

    \maketitle

    \section{Section 1}

    \begin{pspicture}(7,7)
    \pnodes(0,0){A}(7,7){B}
    \multidipole(A)(B)\resistor{$R$}%
    \capacitor[linecolor=red]{$C$}%
    \diode{$D$}{}
    \end{pspicture}

    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \xio[plcaddress=I:1/0,plcsymbol=Symbol](0,0)
    \end{pspicture}
    % 
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(1,1)
    \xic[plcaddress=I:1/0,plcsymbol=Symbol](0,0)
    \end{pspicture}
    %
    \vspace{2cm}
    %
    \begin{pspicture}(-1,-1)(3,3)
    \xio[plcaddress=I:1/1,plcsymbol=Symbol](0,0)(A)
    \xic[plcaddress=I:1/1,plcsymbol=Symbol](2,2)(B)
    \multidipole(A)(B){\xio}%
    {\xic}.
    \end{pspicture}
    %
    \end{document}
```